# Is AMEOBA ArcToolbox compatible with ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, clustering

Is the **[AMEOBA ArcToolbox](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~geojared/tools.htm)** compatible with ArcGIS 10.2?

My error (when trying to run one of its tools) is noted below.

[image]
(click to enlarge)

Comment: You need to add some detail to your question, I'd start with the actual text of your error message instead of a barely-legible screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! Some more details will help here –  What is AMEOBA? What version of Windows are you running? If you past the actual text of your error it will help out. Context is everything!

Comment: It seems a spatial clustering technique, see reference to ArcToolbox tool here: http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~geojared/tools.htm

Comment: @Dan C that's good advice, but you might like to know that this screenshot (as well as many others on this site that initially look poor) is quite legible: it magnifies well and the original is available through the `View Image` option when right-clicking on it (at least in many Web browsers).

Comment: I understand that its a tool, however it doesn't seem to work within 10.2.  I will capture the text here shortly.

Comment: The initial issue was the GAL file. The tool requires this instead of the SWM.  That was solved.  However, I have run the tool against the sample data in 10.2 and it worked without error.  Now we are receiving a set of different errors.  I am creating my GAL in GeoDa then manipulating the header.  The header should have the total number of observations only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code of this tool it is throwing an error as the first line for the weights file is not a number. Either you have selected the wrong file or your weights file is not in the format expected by the tool. Looking at the source code the author has put comments in it for what they would expect for each input parameter and they reference in their comments the sample file countryCluster.GAL which starts with a number...

The file you choose is starting with the text "VERSION@10.1..." so I'm guessing you have selected the wrong file for this parameter to the tool and is nothing to do with version compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

The **[home page for AMOEBA](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~geojared/tools.htm)** states:

> These scripts require ArcGIS 8.x or higher

and ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2 is MUCH higher so the original code may well need to be updated.

I recommend that you contact its author whose email address appears on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

The tool works fine, there is not a compatibility issue.  It does however take a GAL file which can be created in GeoDa.  When using the GAL file in ArcGIS it is important to make sure that the header is the total number of observations, while all other columns are sequential.